# Unable to load @ page import in jsp

Tags: jsp

I have a jsp page with following as top lines:

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*" %>
<html>
<head>
..
```

However, when I load this page in browser, it loads verbatim- as a text file. If I remove the first line, it loads as an html file and renders elements on web page. I have tried this in firefox as well as chrome on Linux.

Where is the problem and how can I solve this? Thanks for your answers/comments.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running this from a application container like tomcat? If write your file as a JSP and put in your web application you can access the html with import statements.